# Rotate column titles AND lines in tabular

Tags: tables, rotating

I would like to not only rotate the text in the header of a tabular, but also insert and rotate a vertical lines by 45 degrees (between CaptionR3 and CaptionR4).

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{!{\centering\arraybackslash\vrule width #1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{0.9cm}|L{2.0cm}|l|l}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Caption1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Caption2} & \rot{CaptionR3} & \rot{CaptionR4} \\
\hline      Text1 & Text4 & - \\
\hdashline  Text2 & Text5 & - \\
\hdashline  Text3 & Text6 & - \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

The angle of the rotation can be set by the parameter `\angle`.

A command `\Rot` is defined to rotate the labels (that command does a translation rightwards in order to have a better output).

A command `\MixedRule` must be used in the `\CodeAfter` of `{NiceTabular}` in order to draw the rule corresponding to that label (no symbol `|` should be put in the preamble for those rules).

**You need several compilations.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \ValuePlusOne } { m } 
  { \int_eval:n { \int_use:c { c @ #1 } + 1 } }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \Sec } { m } 
  { \fp_eval:n { secd ( #1 ) } }
\NewDocumentCommand { \Rot } { m }
  { 
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1 em }
      { 
        \hbox_overlap_right:n 
          { 
            \skip_horizontal:n { \fp_to_dim:n { 7 * cosd (\Angle) } } 
            \rotatebox{\Angle}{#1}
          } 
      } 
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand { \MixedRule } { m }
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (2-|#1) ;
    \coordinate (b) at (1-|#1) ;
    \draw (a) -- ($(a)!\Sec{90-\Angle}!\Angle-90:(b)$) ;
    %
    \draw (2-|#1) -- (\ValuePlusOne{iRow}-|#1) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\begin{document}

\def\Angle{45}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|ccc}
Caption 1 & Caption 2 & \Rot{Caption 3} & \Rot{Caption 4} & \Rot{Caption 5}\\ \hline
Text1 & Text4 & -- & -- & -- \\ \hline  
Text2 & Text5 & -- & -- & -- \\ \hline  
Text3 & Text6 & -- & -- & --
\CodeAfter
\MixedRule{4}
\MixedRule{5}
\end{NiceTabular}
    
\bigskip
\def\Angle{60}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|ccc}
Caption 1 & Caption 2 & \Rot{Cap 3} & \Rot{Cap 4} & \Rot{Cap 5}\\ \hline
Text1 & Text4 & -- & -- & -- \\ \hline  
Text2 & Text5 & -- & Text7 & -- \\ \hline  
Text3 & Text6 & -- & -- & --
\CodeAfter
\MixedRule{4}
\MixedRule{5}
\end{NiceTabular}
    
\bigskip
\def\Angle{90}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|ccc}
Caption 1 & Caption 2 & \Rot{Caption 3} & \Rot{Caption 4} & \Rot{Caption 5}\\ \hline
Text1 & Text4 & -- & -- & -- \\ \hline  
Text2 & Text5 & -- & Text7 & -- \\ \hline  
Text3 & Text6 & -- & -- & --
\CodeAfter
\MixedRule{4}
\MixedRule{5}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

The last example is with a value of 90 for the parameter `\Angle`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy peasy way to do it, but you have to adapt the lenght of the dashed line by hand:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{!{\centering\arraybackslash\vrule width #1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{0.9cm}|L{2.0cm}|l|@{}l@{}l}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Caption1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Caption2} & \rot{CaptionR3} &
  \hspace*{-1ex}\rot{\hspace*{-1ex}- - - - - - - - -} &\rot{CaptionR4} \\
\hline      Text1 & Text4 & - \\
\hdashline  Text2 & Text5 & - \\
\hdashline  Text3 & Text6 & - \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular with rotated, dashed line]

Comment: I have an error when trying to compile your code because of the `\hspace*{-1ex}\rot{...}`. The command `\rot` begins with the `\omit` present in `\multicolumn` and an `\omit` must always occur at the beginning of the cell (after expansion).

Comment: @F.Pantigny You are right, I didn't notice yesterday. Maybe because the TeX ignores the error. Hopefully somebody comes up with a better idea. If we delete the first `\hspace*`, the lines don't match that well.